# Is it possible to use numpy.argmax with a custom field of objects in a list?

Tags: python, numpy

Something like:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.id = n

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

my_list = []
my_list.append(Test(1))
my_list.append(Test(2))
my_list.append(Test(3))
```

Would it be possible to get the element in the list with the maximum or minimum id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't even need to resort to `numpy.argmax()` in your example.  Since your objects are in a standard Python list, you can also use Python's built-in `max()` function:

```
index = max(range(len(my_list)), key=lambda i: my_list[i].id)
```

or

```
index = max(enumerate(my_list), key=lambda x: x[1].id)[0]
```

will also give you the index of the item with maximal `id`.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the `__cmp__` operator for class `Test`, `argmax` should behave as expected.